# It is possible to add an asterisk to certain values ​in a column that meet a certain condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, addition

```
id <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
value <- c(3, 4.1, 13.2, 8.0, 10.1)
df <- data.frame(id, value)
```

like this:

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3 |
| b | 4.1 |
| c | 13.2* |
| d | 8.0 |
| e | 10.1* |

In this case I have a dataframe and I want to place an asterisk for all those values ​​greater than or equal to 10

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather add an asterisk column so that the values are not converted to characters.

```
> within(df, {
+   v10 <- value >= 10
+   ' ' <- c('', '*')[v10 + 1L]
+   rm(v10)
+   })
  id value  
1  a   3.0  
2  b   4.1  
3  c  13.2 *
4  d   8.0  
5  e  10.1 *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$value = ifelse(df$value >= 10, paste0(df$value, "*"), df$value)
```

Or with [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr):

```
dplyr::mutate(df, value = ifelse(value >= 10, paste0(value, "*"), value))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution worked perfectly for me. Additionally, if instead of adding an asterisk to a value it is greater than or less than a condition, how would you paste that asterisk if it is outside a range, for example if the value is below 5 or greater than 10?

Comment: you could use the function `between(), then check for numbers not between using `!`

Comment: e.g. `!between(x, 1, 10)` returns true if x is not between 1 and 10